# CSS responsive square with contents centered

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a responsive design layout in which the left grid item (see below) is always square and centers the contents within that square. I've tried different combinations of padding, margin, flex, etc. Can't seem to create a consistent result.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-50 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 0;
  max-width: 45%;
  flex-basis: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-50">
    <img
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/2/22/SpongeBob_SquarePants_logo_by_Nickelodeon.svg/1920px-SpongeBob_SquarePants_logo_by_Nickelodeon.svg.png"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="grid-50">
    SpongeBob SquarePants
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: grid to start from should help, then vertical-align and a pseudo to stretch the box to a square ratio and finally flex for the box holding text. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vYLYaOV

Comment: using your code snippet appears to work until I put a vertical image in.

Comment: this will happen with any display layout , the pseudo stretches it untill it's a square, if it's already taller, it doesn't shrink the container, unless the img is set in absolute position , parent in relative position and img size holded via heigh/width or max-heigh/max-width . So if img is absolute, your square can remain a square anytime.

Comment: pen updated to demonstrate previous comment : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vYLYaOV

Answer (score -1):

Apply `display:flex` to `.grid-50`. Something like this should work:

```
.grid-50 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Problem is that doesn't appear to make it a square.